# Sync to Outlook Removal

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, outlook, task-list, sync

I have read that in SharePoint tasks the sync to Outlook button is being removed this September, is there going to be a new syncing feature, or another way to achieve this function? Also if anyone knows of a tool or plug in that can aggregate Outlook and SharePoint please share!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a tab in your web browser.
2. Log in to SharpSpring.
3. Click User Menu > Settings in SharpSpring's top toolbar.
4. Click User Email Settings, located under My Account in the left panel.
5. Select Outlook in the Provider drop-down menu.
6. Enter the Outlook email address that will be synced in the Username field.
7. Enter the password used to log in to the Outlook email address in the Password field.
8. Select Inbox in the Inbox drop-down menu.
9. Select Sent in the Outbox drop-down menu.
10. Click Connect.
11. Click Close.